# How to duplicate specific row in table (JS/JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jakarta-ee

I am trying to duplicate a specific line in my table when I click in "duppliquer" button

See my code to create my table below

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table order-list" data-page-length='100'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 2</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Test1</td>
        <td align="center">Test2</td>
        <td align="center">Test3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a class="Duppliquer" title="Duppliquer" data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons">control_point_duplicate</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Test4</td>
        <td align="center">Test5</td>
        <td align="center">Test6</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a class="Duppliquer" title="Duppliquer" data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons">control_point_duplicate</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I know that I have to use Javascript ou Jquery, but I don't understand how to get the line that i want to duplicate

I made a lot of research on this subject, but cannot find any answer ...

Answer (score 2):

You should get the current `row` element and then use `clone(true)` function to clone it and finally append the cloned row into the table so that it is placed after the current `row` elemnt. Here is an example:

```js
$(".Duppliquer").click(function(){
var $rw = $(this).closest( "tr" );
var $new_rw = $rw.clone( true );
$rw.after($new_rw);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table order-list" data-page-length='100'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 2</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Test1</td>
        <td align="center">Test2</td>
        <td align="center">Test3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a class="Duppliquer" title="Duppliquer" data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons">control_point_duplicate</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Test4</td>
        <td align="center">Test5</td>
        <td align="center">Test6</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a class="Duppliquer" title="Duppliquer" data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons">control_point_duplicate</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**EDIT:**
according to the comments the following code will also change the first cell of copied row:

```js
$(".Duppliquer").click(function(){
var $rw = $(this).closest( "tr" );
var $new_rw = $rw.clone( true );
var $first_cell = $new_rw.find("td:first");
$first_cell.html($first_cell.html() + " Copy!");
$rw.after($new_rw);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table order-list" data-page-length='100'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 2</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Test1</td>
        <td align="center">Test2</td>
        <td align="center">Test3</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a class="Duppliquer" title="Duppliquer" data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons">control_point_duplicate</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Test4</td>
        <td align="center">Test5</td>
        <td align="center">Test6</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a class="Duppliquer" title="Duppliquer" data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="material-icons">control_point_duplicate</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's perfect
What if I want to add a character to my first (duplicate) column. Like if I duplicate the line ("Test4", "Test5", "Test6") but instead I want ("Test4 - BIS", "Test5", "Test6")
Is that possible to do it ?

Comment: yes you can. you should get your `td` target elemtn from the cloned element and then manipulate it's content as you want.

Comment: Ok, so I made something like this "var $cell = $rw.closest("td");"
But how can I get my first cell ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//I also recommend using lowercase ids and classes.
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.Duppliquer', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var row = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
copy = row.clone();
copy.insertAfter(row);
});
});
```

Comment: I think you should pass `true` as an argument to your `clone` otherwise it won't clone the events.

Comment: I don't have to because the event is bound to the document `$(document).on('click', '.Duppliquer')` will always catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery find:

```
  $('#myTable').find('tr').click(function () {
     var indx = $(this).index() +1; --gets row index
     var tr = $(this); --gets row

  });
```